# Virtual Earth 6.3 set language

Tags: virtual-earth

I am loading https://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3 but I'd like to change language dynamically like if I change website language I would change language also in route.Itinerary.Segments[i].Instruction stuff... is there a way? 
Thanks everyone!

Cheers 
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the mkt parameter of the URL to set the culture as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427600.aspx

Note that the v6.3 control is really old and the documentation for it was taken offline a while back (thus the reason for pointing to the v7 documentation above - works for the most part with v6.3). The v6.3 control supports a very small number of languages. You should be using the Bing Maps v7 control which supports a lot more languages and has a lot more features, along with having much better performance.

As for dynamically changing the culture, you can try reloading the map control with a different mkt value by adding a script reference to your page, however this will require you to reload your map as well. Alternatively you can reload the page and change the mkt parameter of the URL using server side code.